# Java Lambda Expression message formatting, break and string concatenation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

just a quick question around Lambda Expressions. I have the following text:

> {"hosts":[{"disks":[{"path":"/","space_used":0.608}],"hostname":"host1"},{"disks":[{"path":"/","space_used":0.79},{"path":"/opt","space_used":0.999}],"hostname":"host2"},{"disks":[{"path":"/","space_used":0.107}],"hostname":"host3"}]}

Which I'd like to format the above to each line reading:

> {"hostname": "host1", "disks":["Path '/' had utilised 60.8%"]}
>
> {"hostname": "host2", "disks":["Path '/' had utilised 79%", "Path '/opt' had utilised 99.9%"]}
>
> {"hostname": "host3", "disks":["Path '/' had utilised 10.7%"]}

I've tried a few permutations around .stream().map() and then .collect() but somehow I came up short in getting to the output I needed. Any help is much appreciated and apologies if the question is rather n00bish. Thanks.

Comment: why you don't use a JSON library instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Jackson 2 Library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Using-Jackson2-with-Maven) to convert your JSON-String to Java objects.

In your concrete case you could e.g. create the following classes:

---

**Disk.java**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"path", "space_used"})
public class Disk implements Serializable {

  private final static long serialVersionUID = -6127352847480270783L;

  @JsonProperty("path")
  private String path;

  @JsonProperty("space_used")
  private Double spaceUsed;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  @JsonProperty("path")
  public String getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  @JsonProperty("path")
  public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  @JsonProperty("space_used")
  public Double getSpaceUsed() {
    return spaceUsed;
  }

  @JsonProperty("space_used")
  public void setSpaceUsed(Double spaceUsed) {
    this.spaceUsed = spaceUsed;
  }

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }
}
```

---

**Host.java**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"disks", "hostname"})
public class Host implements Serializable {

  private final static long serialVersionUID = -1972892789688333505L;

  @JsonProperty("disks")
  private List<Disk> disks = null;

  @JsonProperty("hostname")
  private String hostname;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  @JsonProperty("disks")
  public List<Disk> getDisks() {
    return disks;
  }

  @JsonProperty("disks")
  public void setDisks(List<Disk> disks) {
    this.disks = disks;
  }

  @JsonProperty("hostname")
  public String getHostname() {
    return hostname;
  }

  @JsonProperty("hostname")
  public void setHostname(String hostname) {
    this.hostname = hostname;
  }

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }
}
```

---

**HostContainer.java**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"hosts"})
public class HostContainer implements Serializable {

  private final static long serialVersionUID = 7917934809738573749L;

  @JsonProperty("hosts")
  private List<Host> hosts = null;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  @JsonProperty("hosts")
  public List<Host> getHosts() {
    return hosts;
  }

  @JsonProperty("hosts")
  public void setHosts(List<Host> hosts) {
    this.hosts = hosts;
  }

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }

}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
  public void parseMessage() throws IOException {
    String msg = "{\"hosts\":[{\"disks\":[{\"path\":\"/\",\"space_used\":0.608}]," +
                 "\"hostname\":\"host1\"},{\"disks\":[{\"path\":\"/\",\"space_used\":0.79}," +
                 "{\"path\":\"/opt\",\"space_used\":0.999}],\"hostname\":\"host2\"}," +
                 "{\"disks\":[{\"path\":\"/\",\"space_used\":0.107}],\"hostname\":\"host3\"}]}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // This object will contain all the information you need, access it using e.g. getHosts();
    HostContainer hostContainer = mapper.readValue(msg, HostContainer.class);
  }
```